# WCF JSON Return Service should return Single Escape Sequence

Tags: c#, string, wcf, utf-8

What i am doing for changing html codes to JavaScript escapes is :

```
string input = "&#2358;&#2381;&#2352;&#2368;&#2327;&#2306;&#2327;..."

var output = Regex.Replace(input, @"&#([0-9]*);", 
               x => String.Format("\\u{0:X4}", int.Parse(x.Groups[1].Value)));
or alternately;

var output = String.Join("", WebUtility.HtmlDecode(input)
                   .Select(x => "\\u" + ((int)x).ToString("X4")));
```

But now i have a problem that when i am sending this data through wcf service in json format. and i am getting values accordingly.
but only the output variable is going wrong which is in this format:

\\u0026\\u0023\\u0032\\u0033\\u0033\\u0037\\u003B\\u0026\\u0023\\u0032\\u0033\\u0037\\u0035\\u003B\\u0026\\u0023\\u0032\\u0033\\u0033\\u0038\\u003B\\u0026\\u0023\\u0032\\u0033\\u0036\\u0034\\u003B\\u0020\\u0026\\u0023\\u0032\\u0033\\u0032\\u0035\\u003B\\u0026\\u0023\\u0032\\u0033\\u0035

i don't want **'\\u0026'** but want only **'\u0026'** in response.
i have tried everything like:

```
output.Replace("\\","'\'");
output.Replace("\\",@"\");
```

but didn.t work here.

Here is my WCF Service method:

```
 [OperationContract(Name = "GetByCity")]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "/GetByCity/DeviceType={DeviceType}&CityId={id}&Limit={limit}", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
                    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        NewsList GetByCity(string DeviceType, string id, string limit);
```

Now i don't know where to define utf-8 format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Unicode escpace sequence `\u....` is used in C# source code and it's used in JSON formatted data but it's not used in C# string. C# strings fully support Unicode and have a direct representation for all Unicode characters.

If required in the transmitted JSON data, the WCF service will create the escape sequence automatically. But if the strings already contain these escape sequences, then the WCF service will add more escaping so the unnecessary escape sequences will be retained after the JSON data has been parsed.

So in order to fix your problem, you will need to replace the HTML entites (`&#....;`) with the real Unicode character, i.e. `&#2358;` needs to be replaced with the character having the Unicode code point 2358:

```
var output = Regex.Replace(input, @"&#([0-9]*);", 
           x => new String((char) int.Parse(x.Groups[1].Value), 1) );
```

Comment: ::Your answer is totally correct i get my solution but ri8 now i want to convert these html codes "&#2358;&#2381;&#2352;&#2368;&#2327;&#2306;&#2327;..."
to some utf-8 format string like this: "\u0928\u0908 \u0926\u093f\u0932\u094d&zwj;\u0932\u0940\/\u092e\u0941\u0902\u092c\u0908."
because i want to use this into mobile device. which support only utf-8 format.

Comment: The WCF service will generate them automatically if they are required. But with UTF-8, they are not required because UTF-8 is capable of representing the Unicode characters directly. And since your mobile devices understand UTF-8, I don't see no reason for using the Unicode escape sequences. (You will need them if you have ASCII or ISO-8859-1 encoding.)

Comment: but when i am sending the values in json format to the device it is not rendering i dont know why is this happening?
i mean it is not showing proper format it is showing a different language dnt know what??

Comment: You might want to open a new question that focuses on what's going wrong on the device and provides all the necessary data (OS, programming language, JSON library, parsing code, display code, sample JSON data etc.). It could also help if you used some tool to capture the transmitted data and analyzed it. If the data looks okay, it can be used for the follow-up question. If not, then we have a further indication of where the mistake might be.

Comment: yeah i think u r ri8 okk i will ask a new question...
BTW thanks for fast reply.
And i accept this answer as this is give me what i wanted although it is a problem at my end only